# Owl carousel 2 with ajax content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, owl-carousel

I searched a lot in internet for this and nothing working for me. Here is the relevant codes. I tried to follow this link [Owl carousel with ajax demo](http://www.jq22.com/demo/OwlCarousel2/demos/ajax.html), but may be something i missed.

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer-gallery" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
   url: siteUrl,
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
       page_no: pageNumber,
   },
   success: function(data) {
        if(data.status == 200)
             owl.trigger('insertContent.owl',[data.html]);
   },
   error: function(e) {
   }
```

**HTML data from ajax**

```
<div class="item"> image content here </div>
<div class="item"> image content here </div>
```

After the ajax call the initial html is changed like this.

**Changed html**

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded" id="footer-gallery">
    <div class="owl-stage-outer">
           <div class="owl-stage"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```